# memory usage increases when fetching oracle clob column

Tags: python, oracle, fastapi, cx-oracle, clob

I use an API that selects only one CLOB column query from Oracle Database in my Python FastAPI server with Kubernetes.

I'm using Python cx_Oracle library for executing queries.

When I requested API, the memory usage of FastAPI container increased to over 40%.
So Pod was dead when I requested continuously.

Fetched CLOB data size is 8KB.

I'm using the below codes in FastAPI server.

```
    def fetch_one(self, sql: str, args: Dict[str, Any]) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        self._cursor.execute(sql, args)
        self._cursor.rowfactory = self.__make_dict_factory__(self._cursor)
        rows = self._cursor.fetchone()
        self.__close__()
        return rows
```

And I'm using an output type handler as shown below because the CLOB data is Korean.

```
    def __return_strings_as_bytes__(self, cursor, name, default_type, size, precision, scale):
        if default_type == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_VARCHAR:
            return cursor.var(str, arraysize=cursor.arraysize, bypass_decode=True)
        elif default_type == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_CHAR:
            return cursor.var(str, arraysize=cursor.arraysize, bypass_decode=True)
        elif default_type == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_NCHAR:
            return cursor.var(str, arraysize=cursor.arraysize, bypass_decode=True)
        elif default_type == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_NVARCHAR:
            return cursor.var(str, arraysize=cursor.arraysize, bypass_decode=True)
        elif default_type == cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_CLOB:
            return cursor.var(str, self.ARRAY_SIZE, cursor.arraysize, bypass_decode=True)
```

What else can I try?
Thanks in advance.

I want to know why memory usage increases when I fetched only one row with CLOB column.

Comment: Have you tried the same with the new version called python-oracledb? Can you create a standalone example (that doesn't use FastAPI) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You can find out about the renaming of the latest cx_Oracle version to python-oracledb in the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a). Check the LOB doc on the handy new [oracledb.defaults.fetch_lobs = False](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html) setting.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga I tried python-oracle, but it was the same result. I'll try a standalone example too.

Comment: @ChristopherJones What's the differences between fetch_lobs option and output handler? I understand output type handler is the old version of fetch_lobs option. Is there a difference?

Comment: The internals are the same.  Along with your testcase, we'll also need to know how big the LOBs are, what DB version is, whether you tried Thin or Thick modes, and how you are measuring size.

Comment: @ChristopherJones 1) When I checked using lob.size(), clob data size is 7580. 2) I don't know the exact version. 3) I tried python-oracledb thick mode.

Comment: Let us know when you have a testcase (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)